# arch linux autostart Interactive program Written in c++ at boot before tty1 appears

Tags: linux, arch-linux

I'm trying to autostart an interactive C++ program at boot before TTY1 appears.

I have created a file called `/etc/systemd/system/myapp.service` with the following contents:

```
[Unit]
Description=myapp

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/home/xxx/myapp.exe start
StandardOutput=tty
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And then ran

```
sudo systemctl enable myapp
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work as expected.  I can't interact with `myapp`, and I do not want TTY1 to appear until the program ends

---

**UPDATE:** My app now works before the TTY appears.
`/etc/systemd/system/myapp.service` now contains:

```
[Unit]
Description=myapp
After=sysinit.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
StandardOutput=tty
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/home/xxx/myapp.exe start

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

But I still can't interact with my program.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to interact with my program by adding a TTY `StandardInput` line to the systemd service, and disabling the TTY1 systemd service.

Here are the final contents of `/etc/systemd/system/myapp.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=myapp
After=sysinit.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
StandardInput=tty
StandardOutput=tty
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/home/xxx/myapp.exe start

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And here is the command to disable the TTY1 systemd service:

```
sudo systemctl disable getty@tty1.service
```

Now, the program appears interactively on TTY1.